# sorting algorithm with pagination

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, pagination

I want to sort a list of entries and then select a subset (page) of that sorted list. For example; I have 10.000 items and want to have items 101 until 200.
A naive approach would be to first sort all 10.000 items and then select the page; it would mean that items 1 - 100 and 201 - 10.000 are all unnecessarily fully sorted.
Is there an existing algorithm that will only fully sort the items in the page and stops further sorting of an entry once it is clear it is not in the page? source code in C would be great, but descriptions would also be ok

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say there is unnecessary sorting as you can't know if an item will be on the page or not until all items are in sort order.

Comment: It doesn't matter if items 9999 and 9998 are swapped as long as they are after item 200

Comment: How are you going to determine first 200 entries ?

Comment: I can imagine that a quicksort like approach would be an option. If,  after the first iteration, the list is divided into 2 unsorted lists, say of 4000 lower and 6000 higher items, then the 6000 higher items don't have to be sorted any further.

Comment: @coen: that's precisely correct, and if you do that you'll end up with a perfectly good O(n) quickselect algorithm. That's cool if you don't expect most of the pages to ever be requested, but it breaks down if many pages are requested, because the total cost becomes much greater than a cached initial sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the page you want starts with the *nth* "smallest" element (or largest or whatever ordinal scale you prefer). Then you need to divide your partial sorting algorithm into two steps:

1. Find the *nth* element
2. Sort elements {*n*, *n*+1, ..., *n+s*} (where *s* is the page size)

[Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is a sorting algorithm that can be conveniently modified to suit your needs. Basically, it works as follows:

- Given: a list *L* of ordinally related elements.
- If *L* contains exactly one element, return *L*.
- Choose a pivot element *p* from *L* at random.
- Divide *L* into two sets: *A* and *B* such that *A* contains all the elements from *L* which are smaller than *p* and *B* contains all the elements from *L* which are larger.
- Apply the algorithm recursively to *A* and *B* to obtain the sorted sublists *A'* and *B'*.
- Return the list *A* || *p* || *B*, where || denotes appending lists or elements.

What you want to do in step #1, is run Quicksort until you've found the *nth* element. So step #1 will look like this:

- Given: a list *L* of ordinally related elements, a page offset *n* and a page size *s*.
- Choose a pivot element *p* from *L* at random.
- Divide *L* into *A* and *B*.
- If the size of *A*, *#A* = *n-1*, then return *p || B*.
- If *#A* < *n-1*, then apply the algorithm recursively for *L' = B* and *n' = n - #A*
- If *#A* > *n-1*, then apply the algorithm recursively for *L' = A* and *n' = n*

This algorithm returns an unsorted list of elements starting with the *nth* element. Next, run Quicksort on this list but keep ignoring *B* unless *#A < s*. At the end, you should have a list of *s* sorted elements which are larger than *n* elements from the original list but not larger than *n+1* elements from the original list.

The term you want to research is [partial sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting). There is likely to be an implementation of it in C or any sufficiently popular language.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want items p through q out of n.  While sorting would cost O(n·log n) time, the operation you mention can be done in O(n) time (so long as q-p « n) as follows:  Apply an [O(n)-time method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements) to find the pᵗʰ and qᵗʰ values.  Then select only items with values from p to q, in time O(n+k) if k=q-p, or about O(n) time, and sort those items in time O(k·log k), which is about O(1), for net time O(n) if k is O(1).